# Inconsistent Report Export between xls and csv

Tags: reporting, data-export

I have a fairly large report with 97K rows in it, when I try to download the .csv / .xls extensions the export fails to dump out all the data. Has anyone seen such inconsistency with report exports?

- This is a tabular report
- I have no filters on my report and not using fiscal year/ fiscal month to restrict the data.
- I am downloading as Unicode UTF-8 format. (not sure if the file encoding is corrupting the export, would guess not)

( **Known Issue:** https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3MeAAK)

When I open my .xls version I see only 17K records and with .csv its inconsistent, the range is anywhere between 80k to 97K(All records are exported sometimes). I am a sys admin and I can see all the records ( should not matter for this question one of the report does export all the data )

I exported the exact same report as XLS and CSV.

**Report exported as CSV : Has 97 K rows**

[image]

**Report exported as XLS : Has 17K rows**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a timeout issue. Have you tried recreating the report criteria in dataloader?

Comment: @girbot nope, i have raised a case with support, i was going to wait for them and enable background report export and see if async report export would handle this better. I would expect to see a timout error than half dumped data in my reports.

Comment: Agreed, was a long shot. I'm interested to see what you find out.